# conversion from vb asp to C# asp .net

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net

I have a existing large(about 150 pages website) VB .net website and i want to convert it into C# .net website. Please suggest me the efficient tool to achieve this task.
Thanks in advance

Comment: This is off topic for SO.

Answer (score 2):

Try to convert here... It may work... http://converter.telerik.com/

Comment: Is it possible to convert the whole application in single shot.

Comment: install SharpDevelop 4.4 you can convert an entire VB.NET project to C# by opening the solution, right clicking the project in the Projects window and selecting Convert - From VB.NET to C#

Answer (score 1):

```
Yes. We have paid licensed tools or free online tools.One of the best tool implemented by telerik .

http://converter.telerik.com/

http://codeconverter.sharpdevelop.net/SnippetConverter.aspx

http://www.carlosag.net/tools/codetranslator/

http://www.developerfusion.com/tools/convert/vb-to-csharp/
```